# Controlling the location of figcaption relative to a responsive image within a figure using CSS

Tags: html, css, figure

I am putting together a website that needs to display a responsive image where the image is always aligned at the top of the browser, and a caption is pinned to a location that is immediately below and aligned with the left edge of the image.

My image behaves perfectly, but I cannot control the position of the figcaption except relative to the figure. How to control the figcaption relative to the image??? What I want to happen is for the fig caption to align immediately below and AT the left edge of the image (NOT align-center). It always seems to end at the bottom of the figure. Ive read about 25 posts trying to find out how to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Here is my HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<link href="test02.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

    <figure class="niag">
        <img class="hero" src ="Images/IMG_5678.jpg" alt=""/>
        <figcaption>This is one of my nicest images</figcaption>
    </figure>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is my CSS

```
.niag {
/*      display: block;*/
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px dotted gray;    
    }
.niag figcaption {

    border: 1px dotted blue;
    position: absolute;
/*    bottom: 0;*/
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    }
.hero {
    display: block;
    height: 85vh;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    object-position: top;
    }
```

Comment: instead bottom:0; use top:100%; , then mind a margin or a padding at the bottom of figure , so figcaption do not overlap content below ;)

Comment: So that did not work this is what I did to the CSS: 

@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

.niag {
 border: 1px dotted gray; 
 }
.niag figcaption {
 border: 1px dotted blue;
 top: 100%;
 }
.hero {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 85vh;
 width: 100%;
 object-fit: contain;
 object-position: top;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 }

Comment: have you tried the snippet in the answer below .. or did i misunderstood the question ?(very possible, my average english tricks me often ..) ... text will follow the edge of figure element, not where is seen image resized  inside img tag ....

Comment: First of all - thanks for the suggestion. I did try what you posted below, but then the image no longer resizes as you reduce the width of the browser window.

If I add in width: 100% the image width does reduce with the width of the browser window, but I lose the aspect ratio. So I added back in object-fit: contain; and then I am back to square 1 !!!!

Comment: The image resizes according to the object-fit value. give a border or a background-color to see where image tag stands, then play with object-fit values to see behavior .  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a try to `top:100%` + `margin-bottom`

demo of the idea

```css
* {
  margin:0
}
.niag {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;/* update*/
}

.niag figcaption {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;/* update*/
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.hero {
  display: block;
  height: 85vh;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: top;
}
```

```html
<figure class="niag">
  <img class="hero" src="http://dummyimage.com/1200x600" alt="" />
  <figcaption>This is one of my nicest images</figcaption>
</figure>
next-content
```

If the idea is to set text at the `bottom left` of image, then do not use `object-fit` where `img` tag and visual might not cover same area, instead, and to keep ratio, you may use `max-height` , `display` and `margin`:

```css
* {
  margin:0
}
.niag {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
  margin:0 auto  1.5em;/* update*/
  display:table;
}

.niag figcaption {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;/* update*/
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.hero {
  display: block;
  max-height: 85vh;
  max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<figure class="niag">
  <img class="hero" src="http://dummyimage.com/1200x600" alt="" />
  <figcaption>This is one of my nicest images</figcaption>
</figure>
next-content
```

Some compromise has to be done or a well thought javascript snippet aside to handle your first objective

Comment: by the way, `height:auto;`is useless unless to reset a previous height in earlier CSS rules.

Comment: This last suggestion seems to work. Thanks very much! 
what is the meaning of *{ } ? does it apply the enclosed rule to the whole document? In this case setting the margin to 0 globally? Excuse my ignorance on this aspect of css.

Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisS yes this is used as a reset to any tag . margin, padding and box-sizing are often brought together. But most often, you would use a full css file to reset most tags so the default values will be same through every browsers examples https://cssreset.com/ . If answers are usefull and valuable to you, you may upvote and accept one of them if it totally answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Grid layout for both image auto-sizing and aligning caption with image:

```css
.niag {
    display: grid;
    grid-template: ". image    ."
                   ". caption  ."
                   /   1fr auto 1fr;
    border: 1px dotted gray;    
    }
.niag figcaption {
    grid-area: caption;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    }
.hero {
    grid-area: image;
    display: block;
    height: 85vh;
    }
```

```html
<figure class="niag">
   <img class="hero" src ="http://placekitten.com/800/900" alt=""/>
   <figcaption>My image</figcaption>
</figure>
```